# The rusty Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: beginner, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, rust

To get familiar with the Rust language I've decided to implement the method of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find primes up to a number N.

I have created the following code that both prints the prime number and whether it is prime in tabular format and prints a vector consisting of the prime numbers.

As additional library I'm using the external library [bit-vec](http://contain-rs.github.io/bit-vec/bit_vec/).

```
extern crate bit_vec;

const MAXIMUM_PRIME: u32 = 1000;

use bit_vec::BitVec;

fn main() {
    let mut prime_bit_vector = BitVec::from_elem((MAXIMUM_PRIME + 1) as usize, true);
    let sqrt_prime = ((MAXIMUM_PRIME as f64).sqrt() as u32) + 1;

    for i in 2..(sqrt_prime+1) {
        if prime_bit_vector[i as usize] {
            let mut j = i * i;
            while j <= MAXIMUM_PRIME {
                prime_bit_vector.set(j as usize, false);
                j += i;
            }
        }
    }

    let maximum_prime_length = MAXIMUM_PRIME.to_string().len();
    for i in 0..(MAXIMUM_PRIME+1) {
        println!("{index:<width$} {is_prime}", index = i, is_prime = prime_bit_vector[i as usize], width = maximum_prime_length as usize);
    }

    let primes: Vec<_> = prime_bit_vector.iter().enumerate().filter(|t| t.1).map(|t| t.0).collect();
    println!("Primes: {:?}", primes);
}
```

Comment: You method is doing way to much. You really should separate the responsibilities into methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start, let me **heartily compliment** you on your code! You have clearly put effort into learning what idiomatic Rust code looks like. Spacing of operators seems to be accurate, and using code like `Vec<_>` is top-notch.

I actually took a long time to write a review because there didn't seem to be much to say! After a bit, there were some *small* things:

1. I agree that your code could be improved by splitting out some functions:

   1. Separates the concerns of building the primes and printing them.
   2. Allows parameterizing the maximum easier.
   3. Cordons off the mutability of the `BitVec` to a smaller scope.
   4. Gives names to what is being printed.
2. Instead of passing the maximum prime when printing, it can be based on the size of the `BitVec`. It's a *little* odd as you have to subtract one, so maybe you might want to create a type for the primes that abstracts that away...
3. Generally, I'd recommend avoiding array indexing due to performance concerns — indexing has slight overhead due to bounds checking. I'm not sure if that applies for a `BitVec` though. I still like the `enumerate` solution better.
4. From previous Sieves, I *think* that you may want to write `((MAXIMUM_PRIME as f64).sqrt() as u32) + 1` as `(MAXIMUM_PRIME as f64).sqrt().ceil() as u32`. I think that's more correct in more cases, and probably communicates intent better.

```
extern crate bit_vec;

const MAXIMUM_PRIME: u32 = 1000;

use bit_vec::BitVec;

fn primes_up_to(max: u32) -> BitVec {
    let mut prime_bit_vector = BitVec::from_elem((max + 1) as usize, true);
    let sqrt_prime = ((max as f64).sqrt() as u32) + 1;

    for i in 2..(sqrt_prime+1) {
        if prime_bit_vector[i as usize] {
            let mut j = i * i;
            while j <= max {
                prime_bit_vector.set(j as usize, false);
                j += i;
            }
        }
    }

    prime_bit_vector
}

fn print_table(prime_bit_vector: &BitVec) {
    let max = prime_bit_vector.len() - 1;
    let maximum_prime_length = max.to_string().len();

    for (i, is_prime) in prime_bit_vector.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("{index:<width$} {is_prime}", index = i, is_prime = is_prime, width = maximum_prime_length);
    }
}

fn print_primes(prime_bit_vector: &BitVec) {
    let primes: Vec<_> = prime_bit_vector.iter().enumerate().filter(|t| t.1).map(|t| t.0).collect();
    println!("Primes: {:?}", primes);
}

fn main() {
    let prime_bit_vector = primes_up_to(MAXIMUM_PRIME);
    print_table(&prime_bit_vector);
    print_primes(&prime_bit_vector);
}
```

---

In the future, two Rust enhancements will help the code look even better:

1. Someday we will have inclusive ranges, which would transform `x..(y+1)` into some nicer syntax (perhaps `x...y`?).
2. Someday the `step_by` range iterator adapter will exist, which would transform the `j += i` to something like `((i*i)...MAXIMUM).step_by(i)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your review! I really appreciate the effort you have put into this, for a moment I had even thought that it would never get a review. I have just put a follow-up question up on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/130101/multiple-rusty-sieves-of-eratosthenes though I have to mention that I made this several days ago and that I have not incorporated some of your comments on this post.